# ¿porque la matriz no me muestra el valor de la celda especificada?

Tags: c++

La **matriz** me devuelve resultados en blanco, como si de nada se tratase, el código es bien simple y al pedir los datos de la matriz para que me muestre el ***"Hola"***, no me aparece nada más que **una línea vacía y debajo el texto de system pause** que dice ***"presione una tecla para continuar..."***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
std::string matriz [1][1] ={("hola")};
std::cout << matriz [1][1] << std::endl;
system ("Pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos errores:

- En C++ la numeración de los arreglos comienza del 0.
- Deberías usar llaves para denotar una lista. En la lista (matriz) tienes una sublista (columna o fila) encerrada por paréntesis en lugar de llaves.

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>

  int main(){
      std::string matriz [1][1] ={{"hola"}};
      std::cout << matriz[0][0] << std::endl;
      system("Pause");
  }
  ```

---

Consideraciones:

- Si quieres portabilidad, evita el uso de `system`. Puedes usar [`std::cin.get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) para obtener un efecto similar.
- [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) además de escribir un salto de línea llama a [`flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush). No hay de que preocuparse, pero si el rendimiento es importante, considera usar "\n" o '\n'.

Comment: muchas gracias, anotare los datos para que nunca se me olviden, muy agradecido de tu respuesta, está hecha con intenciones profesionales y gracias a eso sé lo que se ahora, muchas gracias de verdad.